# How to design good schema & security rule for managing user data in 2 modes: admin & user in Firebase

Tags: firebase

Lemme introduce my problem, I would like to build a product like advisory service, that user send their question (post), and then admin give him an advice.

So this is my schema: 
[image]

About security, I prefer user can get their own questions only, but admin can see all of them.

```
{
    "rules": {
        "profiles": {
            "$uid": {
                ".read": "auth != null && (auth.uid == $uid || root.child('profiles').child(auth.uid).child('role').val() == 'admin')",
                ".write": "auth != null && (auth.uid == $uid || root.child('profiles').child(auth.uid).child('role').val() == 'admin')"
            }
        },
        "posts": {
            "$uid": {
                ".read": "auth != null && (auth.uid == $uid || root.child('profiles').child(auth.uid).child('role').val() == 'admin' || root.child('profiles').child(auth.uid).child('role').val() == 'admin')",
                ".write": "auth != null && (auth.uid == $uid || root.child('profiles').child(auth.uid).child('role').val() == 'user')"
            },
            ".read": "auth != null && (root.child('profiles').child(auth.uid).child('role').val() == 'admin' || root.child('profiles').child(auth.uid).child('role').val() == 'mod')"   
        },
        ".read": false,
        ".write": false
    }
}
```

From user-view, it looks quite good because I can get quickly posts belong to that user. However, from admin-view, it really bad:

1. I don't how to purely get all user's posts. I have to get all users, then get posts of user later.
2. I can not get exactly trigger event by using $watch. When an user add new post, I got "child_changed" event (of user by id), not "child_added" (of post by id)
3. I'd like to query all questions that not response from admin yet, but dont know how.

A trade-off, I've stored all post in plain array e.g:

```
posts: {
    <post_id>: {
        uid: <user_id>,
        ....
    }
}
```

But then I've got problem with access rule, can not restrict users to access their own data only. Without read-rule, user can bruce-force user-id to get data.

Would you please give me a hint. Thank you in advance!

P/S: I'm working on Firebase w/ angular JS, no backend server

Comment: I see JSON but a reference to the framework or programming language you use would be helpful. Have you tried [nodejs](http://jedireza.github.io/drywall/) or [Python Django](http://djangoproject.com). Specialy django delivers it "nearly" out of the box.

Comment: @PeterRosemann: I'm working on Firebase w/ angular JS, no backend server